# GooglePlus Authentication in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 App (WINRT)**. 
How to do **GooglePlus Authentication (SignIn via GooglePlus)** in Windows Phone 8.1 App** without using MVVM/MVC**?

I used **Web Authentication via Webbrowser control in Windows Phone 8.0 App** but **Windows Phone 8.1 WebView Control** does not have **Navigating event**.

Can anyone help me?

---

According to Mr. Filip Skakun, I wrote:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Data.Json;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Security.Authentication.Web;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Web.Http;


namespace webbrokerFinal
{

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Connect();


            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }


        string FacebookClientIDString = "000000000000";
        string FacebookCallbackUrlString = " https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

        private  void Connect()
        {
            try
            {
                String FacebookURL = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + FacebookClientIDString + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeUriString(FacebookCallbackUrlString) + "&scope=read_stream&display=popup&response_type=token";

                System.Uri StartUri = new Uri(FacebookURL);
                System.Uri EndUri = new Uri(FacebookCallbackUrlString);

                WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(StartUri, EndUri, null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);

            }
            catch (Exception Error) >> The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
            {
                //
                // Bad Parameter, SSL/TLS Errors and Network Unavailable errors are to be handled here.
                //
            }



        }


        public async void ContinueWebAuthentication(WebAuthenticationBrokerContinuationEventArgs args)
        {
            WebAuthenticationResult result = args.WebAuthenticationResult;


            if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
            {
                await GetFacebookUserNameAsync(result.ResponseData.ToString());
            }
            else if (result.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }

        private async Task GetFacebookUserNameAsync(string webAuthResultResponseData)
        {
            //Get Access Token first
            string responseData = webAuthResultResponseData.Substring(webAuthResultResponseData.IndexOf("access_token"));
            String[] keyValPairs = responseData.Split('&');
            string access_token = null;
            string expires_in = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < keyValPairs.Length; i++)
            {
                String[] splits = keyValPairs[i].Split('=');
                switch (splits[0])
                {
                    case "access_token":
                        access_token = splits[1]; //you may want to store access_token for further use. Look at Scenario5 (Account Management).
                        break;
                    case "expires_in":
                        expires_in = splits[1];
                        break;
                }
            }

            //Request User info.
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + access_token));
            JsonObject value = JsonValue.Parse(response).GetObject();
            string facebookUserName = value.GetNamedString("name");


        }
    }
}
```

But giving me error:
**The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd start with [`WebAuthenticationBroker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx). It's a sort of wrapper around `WebView` you use for all OAuth.

Comment: the link you shared has an example of facebook, but can you help me in linkedIn authentication and googlePlus authentication ?

Comment: Giving error  The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE) on executing                 WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(StartUri, EndUri, null, WebAuthenticationOptions.None);

Comment: Sample with Google, Twitter, Facebook and Flickr is here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122